# Read File line by line, then perform some action when finished (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a large file (19MB) and inserting data into my mongoose DB. Everything works fine, except when it is done iterating through the file my console just sits there. How would I tell my program to make the console either exit, or execute a function when finished?

```
function prepareDatabase(){
  let lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('names.tsv')
  });

  lineReader.on('line',(line)=>{
    let elements = line.split('\t');
    let Entry = new ChebiEntry();
    Entry.name = elements[4]
    Entry.id = elements[1];
    Entry.save();
    console.log(`Inserted ${Entry.name}`);
  });
  return; // This does not do anything?!
}
```

Comment: close the db connection, or `process.exit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line reader does have a callback for when the whole file has been read.

```
lr.on('end', function () {
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I had to change it to process.exit(); to work

Comment: @Raven no problem. Just mark the answer correct if that's what you needed. That way the question is complete.